# Is it okay to use deep namespaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've decided to follow suit with the namespacing method defined in this article:

http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

Is it good practice to go more than one level deep with namespacing? For example if I have a namespace of 'app' and wanted to store all my components in their own namespace I might have 'app.components' and so on. I might go even further with 'app.components.visual'.

Secondly I am confused as to how constructors fit into this pattern. Do you just put the constructor inside the self-executing function and reference it like:

```
var test = new app.MyConstructor()
```

Again, is this good practice?

Comment: It took me whole minutes to understand "Name Spacing" is about a namespace... I was looking for strings and spaces, or spaces in your code.

Comment: Ok. Edited it to read 'namespacing'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go as deep as you like.  For example, this might be cool:

```
app.ui.widgets.Clock
```

And so would this:

```
var clock = new app.ui.widgets.Clock('UTC');
```

And if you think thats ugly, then create a local reference for the constructor object:

```
var Clock = app.ui.widgets.Clock;
var clock1 = Clock('UTC');
var clock2 = Clock('PST');
```

Using objects to create logical namespaces that group related modules/constructors/objects/function is a very good idea, especially in a much larger codebase.